# Android Button color not changing programatically

Tags: android, button, colors

I have this piece of code, which is expected to change the color of the button to BLUE, but it does not have any effect.
The code goes into this if statement but does not change the color. On the other hand , the same statement when used earlier does actually change the color of the button. Why is this so?

```
   if(t.equals("a"))
                 {
                     Toast toast5=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"a found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                     toast5.show();          
                     btn6.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                 }
```

Comment: @HJV I already mentioned that it does.

Comment: then try with btn6.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: @HJV This works..but it fills the color in some portions outside the button as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Get Handle for the Tab buttons
Button btnTab1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tab1);
Button btnTab2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tab1);

// set the colors correctly
btnTab1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightblue);
btnTab2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkblue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
btn6.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You implement for this code,

```
    btn6.setBackgroundColor(Color.colorChoose);
    btn6.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable);
    btn6.setBackgroundResource(int resid);
```